# "would" vs "would have" in “I would remember it”

Tags: conditional-constructions

> "Are you sure you did not see her?"

What should be the ideal response from below choices :

> "Yes, if I saw her, I would remember it."

OR

> "Yes, if I had seen her, I would remember it."

OR

> "Yes, if I had seen her, I would have remembered it."

I think second one is correct but all other options are not looking wrong too.

**Some context:**  My boss's secretory has not come and he is asking me if I had seen her. I think its fairly obvious what I intend to answer,but all the three option are looking similar.So point out the subtle difference to me, if any.

Answer (score 1):

All 3 versions are acceptable English, but the second one, "*Yes, if I had seen her, I would remember it*" is probably the most natural sounding.

Comment: could you please tell me differences in these 3 in  one or two lines?

Comment: @Prof-Wiz Do you still require to learn the answer of your question?

Answer (score 0):

The differences are a bit difficult to explain.

For example, the way I would personally respond would have been:

> "Are you sure you did not see her?"

> "Yeah, I'm sure. I'd remember if I had seen her."

or

> "Yeah, I'm sure. I'd know if I had seen her."

and the variants go on ... "Had I seen her, I'd remember."

In this specific context of the boss asking, I'd probably say something like "Yeah, I'm sure I haven't seen her. Had I, I would tell you." (or "Had I've, I would've told you") Which implies that there's nothing wrong with my memory (because why would/should there be) and points out/reconfirms that had I actually in fact seen the secretary, I would have told the boss the first time he/she asked.

(If the boss is a native speaker: Native speakers tend to do this double confirmation question thing when they're surprised (especially when looking for something/someone)... "Are you *sure* you haven't seen XYZ?!" **Usually** it's not meant literally (as in questioning the other person's memory or questioning the other person's honesty) ... it *could*, but quite often it's just an expression that expresses (1) an element of surprise/frustration that you can't find XYZ and **(2)** expresses that you **really want** to find XYZ. (As opposed to asking once in passing - which could indicate a lower level of importance)

Answer (score 0):

They're all ok, but #2 is best. Slight differences in meaning, I think due to the two meanings of "remember":

1. "To file away information for late retrieval" (I must remember to get milk)
2. "To retrieve information that has been filed away" (I remember milking a cow once.)

> "Yes, if I saw her, I would remember it."

She is a memorable person. If I saw her, that's an event I would not forget. (Meaning 1)

> "Yes, if I had seen her, I would remember it."

I have a good memory. If I had seen her, I would still be able to remember that. (Meaning 2)

> "Yes, if I had seen her, I would have remembered it."

Could be either:

I have a good memory. If I had seen her, I would still have been able to remember that, when you asked me before. (Meaning 2).

or:

I was looking out for her. If I had seen her, I would have made a note of it. (Meaning 1)